# Object Creation using __new__ method

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a sample object to test the `__new__` and `__init__` method.

Here is my sample code. When I run this - I see `"Its been created"` msg and dont see the `"Initialized"` & `"Deleted"` msg.

```
class Test( object ):
    def __new__(self):
        print 'Its been Created'

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Its been Initialzed'

    def __del__(self):
        print 'Its been Deleted'


T = Test()
```

Comment: er, why are you defining `__del__`, you probably don't want to do that...

Answer (score 3):

`__new__` needs to return an instance of the class (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)).  What you're effectively doing here is returning the instance on `NoneType` (since functions with no explicit return value return `None` (and 'the' in this case because `None` is a special-case singleton in Python)), then having `__init__` of that object called.  The simplest way to fix this would be something like:

```
class Test(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        print 'Creating'
        return super(Test, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print 'Intializing'

    def __del__(self):
        print 'Deleting'
```

This will cause `Test.__new__()` to return the result of `Test`'s superclass' (`object` in this case) `__new__` method as the newly created instance.

It may help you to understand what's going on if you try the following:

```
class A(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        print 'A.__new__'
        return super(A, cls).__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self):
        print 'A.__init__'

    def __del__(self):
        print 'A.__del__'

class FakeA(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        print 'FakeA.__new__'
        return A.__new__()

    def __init__(self):
        print 'FakeA.__init__'

    def __del__(self):
        print 'FakeA.__del__'

a = A()
fa = FakeA()
del a
del fa
```

However, it is important to note that `__del__` [is not guaranteed to be called](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) on every instance every time.